# Jbehave as Data Driven Testing Framework

Tags: testing, jbehave

I have some scenarios written in `Jbehave` and I would like to run it for 1000+ data. The Problem is that I cannot list all data items in 'Examples' because, firstly, it is not maintainable and secondly, I get this data file everyday from an external service.

Is there a way to write a scenario that can take data from the file?

Answer (score 0):

Parameters can be loaded from an external file,
Details with an example are here: http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/parametrised-scenarios.html

> **Loading parameters from an external resource**
>
> The parameters table can also be loaded from an external resource, be
>   it a classpath resource or a URL.

```
  Given a stock of <symbol> and a <threshold> 
  When the stock is traded at <price> 
  Then the alert status should be <status>   
  Examples:
  org/jbehave/examples/trader/stories/trades.table
```

> We need to enable the parser to find the resource with the appropriate
>   resource loader configured via the ExamplesTableFactory:

```
new MostUsefulConfiguration()
         .useStoryParser(new RegexStoryParser(
               new ExamplesTableFactory(new LoadFromClasspath(this.getClass())))
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

I too have same requirement and I think below will be the possible solution.

Implement a method to read the excel sheet and prepare the testData.table before scenario start executes, use @BeforeScenario jbehave annotation in steps java file.

refer this link to implement loading data from external resource http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/parametrised-scenarios.html

```
 @BeforeScenario
   public void prepareTestData(String excelSheetPath) {
      // java code to read given excelSheetPath and prepare a *.table

   }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer?